# How to merge objects with illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Im kind of new to illustrator and wanted to creat a simple logo, so here what I did:

changed background color to black and text color to white, used typography for text, created outlines to convert text to objects and (heres the funny part) I used black pen tool to amend my typography, so most of the corners of the typography are changed. On black background it looks nice, but when I change background color it looks really messy. How should I delete the unwanted part of the drawn typography and merge wanted part with my text objects?

I tried same-> select by fill color, but it doesnt select everything what I need illustrator

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By putting your background on it's own layer, you can show/hide it to help see what you're doing, but it's def not mandatory. You can lock that shape so you're only able to select your typography (whatever fits best here).

The tool you want (for how you're describing things) is the white arrow.

1. Move/Lock your background
2. Select all of your chopped-up type and UNGROUP it
3. Use your white arrow tool to select the shapes for deletion and hit your delete key.
   *If you're only able to grab a single point on one of the shapes you need, and can't select it entirely without grabbing other shapes, use  and single click that single point again. This will automatically select the rest of the points in that shape.
   *If your shape is grouped (as it will be after you convert to outlines), all of the points in the group will be selected (using the  method just mentioned)...hence Step #2 above.

Note: one other thing I do occasionally to help in this type of edit is use View > Preview (command+Y). It shows you *just* the vector lines of the entire illustration. Sometimes you'll catch shapes that don't appear in normal view because of their coloring (or lack there of).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

1. make a copy of the text, hide and lock original.
2. expand appearance -> copy of text
3. ungroup new paths created by last step. Sometimes you will get some empty paths too, delete these.
4. Select all letters and make compound path
5. use the pathfinder to add/subtract/merge/crop two or more paths (the compound text path and the other path). Do these all one at a time to prevent weird results.
6. release the compound path if neccessary to shift the letters around. You won't be able to edit it as text again, so make sure you have the text you want before you do this process.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you have an A which you turned into outlines and then drew a triangle on top of the A? I think what you need is Pathfinder→Merge. Select your A and your triangle and merge them. Do each letter separately.

Also, create some new layers and move your background to a new layer. This will help you keep your letters and the background separate for editing purposes.